# Error at creating simple x y smooth chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a dynamic chart that will change the data set with time, but I am stuck at the first step which is creating a simple chart with a certain limited number of points.

My x values and Y values are at rows 3 and 5.

The code I am trying to run is to create the chart in the same worksheet I am using:

Sub UpdateChart()

```
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Bending Moment along " & ActiveSheet.Name) 'Adjust chart name to your chart

With ChtObj.Chart
    .ChartType = x1XYScatterSmooth
    .SetElement msoElementLegendNone
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 5
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Bending moment"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("D3:H3")
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("D5:H5")
End With
```

End Sub

I am getting error run-time 5, invalid procedure call or argument? This happens at the line of: With ChtObj.Chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the first line of the `With` statement. Hard to see, but there is a `1` instead of an `l`.It should be

```
.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
```

Comment: Hi, still same error :( , the error is in Line With ChtObj.Chart, so it didnt even reach the .ChartType yet..

Comment: Changed a bit in the code and it worked! Thanks again teylyn!